# Running command as root from other application

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

I using c++ in my application to running some terminal command,If i run application as root user is terminal run command like root ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.
You can use su (switch user) in your command to downgrade your rights and risks.

You can test it with the command from C++

```
touch /tmp/farhadtest.tmp
```

and check with `ls -l` from the commandline.